# Alternative to returning template class in extern "C" with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following class (and some specilization for certain types):

```
template <typename Type>
class SimpleOptional {
public:
    SimpleOptional(Type content) : value_(true), content_(content) {}

    // obviously simplified...

private:
    bool value_;
    Type content_;
};
```

which is part of a foreign function interface. The function must be declared with `extern "C"` like this:

```
extern "C" SimpleOptional<char*> b(char *a) {
    return a + 4;  // implicitly constructing SimpleOptional<char*>
}
```

This code works fine with GCC and Clang on macOS and Linux. 
However MSVC does not like it and complains that a function with C linkage may not return a C++ class.

So far I came up with this (where MS_O will only be defined for MSVC):

```
template <typename Type>
class SimpleOptional {
public:
    SimpleOptional(Type content) : value_(true), content_(content) {}

    using ContentType = Type;

private:
    bool value_;
    Type content_;
};

#define MS_O(type) struct { bool b; type::ContentType v; }

extern "C" MS_O(SimpleOptional<char*>) b(char *a) {
    return a + 4;
}
```

Although that fixes the return type issue, I still have no implicit construction and MSVC complains about not being able to convert char* to the return type.

**Is there any kind of workaround that doesn't cost me C++ implicit construction?**

Comment: C cannot directly use `SimpleOptional<char*>`, so it has to be wrapped some way.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to declare `extern "C"` a function that's clearly not callable from C? What will no longer work if you just drop `extern "C"` altogether?